# How do i work with 3 django models linked by a foreign field?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I've been able to display all offices in an election, but have been unable to display all candidates in an office on the same page

**models.py**

```
class Election(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = False, unique = True)
        
class Office(models.Model):
    election = models.ForeignKey(Election, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    
class Candidate(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

**views.py**

```
def poll(request, id):
    
    context = {
        'election' : Election.objects.get(pk=id),
        'off' : Office.objects.all()
    
    }

    return render(request, 'poll.html', context)
```

**poll.html**

```
{% for office in election.office_set.all %}
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3>{{ office.name }}</h3>
            {% for candidate in off.candidate_set.all %}

                <h5><a href="">{{ candidate.name }}</a></h5>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Use `office.candidate_set` instead of `off.candidate_set`.

Comment: Thank u so much. This was also helpful. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line of poll.html, you call "office" from the queryset "election.office_set.all"

Therefore, when you call a subquery of that QS, you have to reference the original name, ie: office, rather than off.

Your final code should look like this:

**poll.html**

```
{% for office in election.office_set.all %}
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3>{{ office.name }}</h3>
            {% for candidate in office.candidate_set.all %}

                <h5><a href="">{{ candidate.name }}</a></h5>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

You also don't need the line

```
'off' : Office.objects.all()
```

in your Views.py.